# What does this SWITCH error mean?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm getting this error for my CASE 5/6/7/8.

I'm sure it's something obvious as it was working before I started adding addition function calls to CASE 4.

What does the error mean?

**error: case label in scope of identifier with variably modified type not containing enclosing switch statement**

```
 switch(menu_selection())
    {
        case 0 :    i = find_empty_record(data_record);       //New record
                    if (i!=-99)
                    {
                        printf("\n\nRecord #%d found to be empty...\n\n",i);
                        data_entry(&data_record[i],i,&array_flag);
                    }
        break;

        case 1  :                                             //Edit
                i=record_selection(array_flag);
                data_entry(&data_record[i],i,&array_flag);
        break;

        case 2  :   display_single(data_record,array_flag);  //Display single record

        break;

        case 3  :                                           //Display all records
                for (i=0;i<30;i++)
                    {
                        print_2_screen(&data_record[i],i,array_flag);
                    }
        break;

        case 4  :   rec_cnt = get_text_file_size(import_file_name); //Import Text File
                    student_record data_record[rec_cnt];
                    import_text_file(data_record,import_file_name,array_flag,rec_cnt);
        break;


        case 5  :   //  Import Binary File
        break;


        case 6  :
                export_text(data_record,rec_cnt,array_flag);//  Save to Text File
        break;

        case 7  :   //  Save to Binary File
        break;

        default :
        break;
    }

}
return 0;
```

Comment: To which line in your code does the error message refer?

Comment: Put the content of `case 4` into braces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> student_record data_record[rec_cnt];
> ```

You can't declare stuff inside a switch.

- Do it before the switch
- Do it in a block:

  ```
  case 4:
  {
      student_record data_record[rec_cnt];
      /* ... */
  }
  ```

Comment: Great, that fixed the errors.  Now it's warning me about unused variables - being the data_record inside the block.  I'm trying to dynamically create a struct array from a text file.  First ever attempt...newbie.  Any ideas of best method?

Comment: @ChefFlambe What are you trying to achieve ? What is the warning ?

Comment: Fixed...only had the declare in a block.

Answer (score 1):

In case 4 you have an array declaration: `student_record data_record[rec_cnt];`

Create an extra block:

```
case 4:   
  {
    rec_cnt = get_text_file_size(import_file_name); //Import Text File
    student_record data_record[rec_cnt];
    import_text_file(data_record,import_file_name,array_flag,rec_cnt);
  }
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case 4: you have declared a new variable which then remains in scope throughout the rest of the switch.  This is only valid in C99 and C++, but will usually generate a warning (not an error) even then.  The solution is to add `{...}` around the case body to limit the scope of any declared variables:

```
    case 4  :
    {
      rec_cnt = get_text_file_size(import_file_name); //Import Text File
                student_record data_record[rec_cnt];
                import_text_file(data_record,import_file_name,array_flag,rec_cnt);
    }
    break;
```

Personally I habitually use this form in all switch/case constructs since it makes maintenance simpler.